# Discord.js — How to read all users in a voice channel and send a private message to each of them containing a random role

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a Wolves/Mafia-esque game on my server. When I write the command `!role 1wolf 2villagers`, I would like to randomly distribute the specified roles by private message (so 1 person receives the wolf role and 2 people receive the villager role) to all the people in a specified voice channel.

The roles are not literal guild roles but simply a message.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith('!role')){
        let channelID = 'your voice channel id';
        message.guild.channels.get(channelID).members.forEach((member) => {
            member.send('Your role is villager!');
        });
    }
});
```

It will get the voice channels, and for each member, send a message to them.

Comment: but where is the wolf ? it has to be !role 1wolf 5villager if 6 members in voice channel randomly send one member wolf role and send 5 member villager role

Comment: I will add prefix+kill prefix+list etc

Comment: msg.guild.channels.get is not a function