# Discord.js - how do I send a message to the specified number of arguments with random members?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to send a private message to the members in voice channel randomly in the number specified in the argument.

I want to do it like this; `prefix+role 4vampir`

I know how to send private messages and filter who is in the voice channel. but I don't know how to send the number of people specified in the argument.

```
let vampire = args[0];
if(vampire.content.startsWith('vampir')){
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js — How to read all users in a voice channel and send a private message to each of them containing a random role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59804968/discord-js-how-to-read-all-users-in-a-voice-channel-and-send-a-private-message)

Comment: I did research after that question and figured out a little bit of its logic, but I still can't do what I'm talking about here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we take the following command structure:
`prefix vampir 4`
Then the following code can do what you need:

```
let msg = *message*
let users = *users in voice channel*
if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix + ' vampir')){
   const numUsers = parseInt(msg.content.split(' ')[2];
   if(isNaN(numUsers)){
     msg.reply(*error message*);
   }else{
      for(var i = 0; i < numUsers; i++){
         var user = users[Math.floor(Math.random()*users.length)];
         *send msg to "user"*
      }

   }
}
```

Just adapt the code as needed to match your command structure

Comment: can i add extra roles ? like prefix+roles 4vampir 3villager 1killer

Comment: You just have to refactor the code so that it matches what you want. Yes this is something you could do.